# Zero tests started with gradle connectedAndroidTest or gradle connectedDebugAndroidTest

Tags: android, automated-tests, instrumented-test

I have some Espresso tests in Android studio in kotlin
Executed "gradle connectedAndroidTest" and "gradle connectedDebugAndroidTest" from cmd having emulator from Android studio turned on or device with usb debbuging
The execution gets "Start 0 tests with ..." and hangs there without anything happening